# Active Directory Account lockout from SharePoint web server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, active-directory

Some process in SharePoint is causing my active directory account to be locked out repeatedly.  It seems to happen on a regular interval (roughly every 4 hours).  I have checked the windows event log and the task scheduler and cannot find any related entries.  This began when I made had to change my password, but has never occurred before when I've done password changes.  My account is not used as a service account anywhere in SharePoint.  Any suggestions on where to look or how to trace this would be greatly apprecitated!

Comment: is it your user account or service account? how do you know sharepoint web server causing this issue?

Comment: It is my user account.  My network administrator was able to pull the "calling computer" name from their monitoring but there is no additional info there about what process.  I do not access that server using my user account -- I log in via a different administrator account.  That, combined with no entries in windows event log, confirms it is not a logon issue.

Comment: do you have any scheduled task configured on the server under your name? or any batch file which run on regular intervals>

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my account.

It happens when you log-in with Service Account to server and then use your account to browse your profile or do some activity.

You need to log-in with service account on the server and then check credential manager it might be saved their which needs to be deleted.